# Where is Ipython's kernal.js located on a Linux Ubuntu system?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

Seems like a silly question, but I cannot find the kernal.js script and I think I need to edit it for my installation...(see reason below if interested, though it's not part of the question). Does anyone know where it would be located on a Linux Ubuntu system? I've tried find and grep, but not getting anywhere.

---

I am serving ipython notebook with a reverse proxy in front, and I am finding that the path to the kernals is wrong, causing errors when I try to load a notebook. I think this line is a problem:

```
var ws_url = this.ws_url + this.kernel_url;
```

Because it excludes the port number suffix from ws_url, which is needed as I am not using the default port with my reverse proxy setup.

I realise it would be an ugly hack to change it, but it's only for development purposes.

Comment: Are you misspelling kernel?  `find / -name kernel.js 2>/dev/null`

Comment: Haha, well spotted! I probably was...how embarrassing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check /usr/share/ipython/notebook/static/services/kernels/js/kernel.js

Comment: Yes it was there, and I probably did misspell when I used find. Thanks both.